# Get value from Gridview for update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

I have this gridview with AutoGenerateEditButton="true":

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridview" runat="server" 
    ShowFooter="True" 
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="odsVolumeSearch" OnRowUpdating="myGridview_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" Visible="false" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="Date" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Items" HeaderText="Items" SortExpression="Items" />            
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my objectDataSource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="myOds" runat="server" 
    DeleteMethod="myDeleteMethod" SelectMethod="mySelectMethod" 
    TypeName="TheirLocation.sqlDataLayer" UpdateMethod="myUpdateMethod">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fromDate" Type="DateTime"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="toDate" Type="DateTime"/>
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="volume" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And this mess right here is my update event handler:

```
protected void gvVolumeList_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvVolumeList.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    String debugString = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + debugString + "');</script>");
}
```

I'm just trying to get the value from my textbox to show up on an alert, but I just cant fix it. I have tried various things and googled like mad but I cant get the value

**EDIT**

I think the problem is that I'm getting the text from the CELL, not the textbox INSIDE the cell. Still dont know what to do though

Comment: Instead of `bound field` i prefer `Template field`, here a sample using template field http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-addupdate-record-using-gridview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void GridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {    
    GridViewRow row = TaskGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    String str = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get Id from your gridview !! 
If you have declared your Bound field visibility false  ,then ur bound field will not be rendered so you can not get its value by using

```
  String debugString = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
```

And you cell index starts from 0 not from 1(If you are trying to get Id) .
Better use RowCommand of gridview or else make your Id property `visible ="true"`

--------------------------OR----------------------------
Use template field

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
                    Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                 ....
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind

```
if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
       HiddenField Id = (HiddenField)row.Cells[0].FindControl("HiddenField1");

       }
```

Comment: I'm not usnig Id, I'm using Items. but thanks for your answer, I'll see if I can do it with a template field

Comment: Try this ...        TextBox chk = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Items");
                                                                        string value = chk.Text;                                            Hope it works by the way ur way is also correct u have to change cell no only ,you are using row.cell[1] instead try row.cell[2] as per ur code above cell position is 3rd which means cell no 2     (cell numbering starts from zero.) Hope it works .

Comment: says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the `string value = chk.Text;` line

Comment: And I've tried changing to different cells. I can get the date-value just fine, but not the input-value from the textbox

Comment: Hi , Well you are using ObjectDataSource  and i think it is a strongly typed datasource , and as per your datasource in your question you have added id , Date but your desired "items" are not added as parameter , So it can be a possibility that you are not getting your desired value. Please suggest if i am in wrong direction .

Comment: Try reconfiguring your ObjectDataSource .

Comment: Try adding one more select parameter to your ObjectDataSource    <SelectParameters>                                       <asp:Parameter Name="fromDate" Type="DateTime"/>                 <asp:Parameter Name="toDate" Type="DateTime"/>
 <asp:Parameter Name="Items" Type="varchar(20)"/>
 </SelectParameters>

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't it the `UpdateParameters` that are used on update?

Comment: Yes UpdateParameters are used for update operations , Well let's go back again to start , are you sure that ur gridview is creating textbox for "Items" ???because we are trying to fetch value by finding (textbox)control. Can u please try to add a template field and try to fetch its value using FindCotrol method

Comment: <asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Textbox ID="Items" runat="server" 
    Value='<%# Eval("Items") %>'</asp:TextBox>                
</ItemTemplate>   
  </asp:TemplateField>                                                            

  TextBox chk = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Items");   
  string value = chk.Text;

Comment: yes, this works, but now all cells are textboxes all the time. I like it better when they are just text until the user presses "edit"

Comment: Use label in templatefield instead of textbox , it will be text as u wanted ,However its an interesting to find a correct way to fetch value from Boundfield , But if u can try label right now u can move forward and we can try to figure out some way to get values from boundfield..Hope it works

Comment: try this i havent tested it yet ,,,,                               string items = ((TextBox)gridvw.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text.Trim();

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that ,,See gridview does not generate textboxes automatically ,i have a confusion about ur requiement , u want textbox on alert when user tries to do update ?yes ? So u can create textbox on alert and assign ur cell value to that textbox , or on Update method create dynamic textbox and assign it cell value , If u want update on grid only than use templatefield make ur textbox readonly and enable it when user tries to update

Comment: ,or create a label and textbox both make textbox visiblity false and label visibility true and when user tries to update make textbox visible and label visibility false and update textbox value .  Sorry if i am unable to help u .

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get control value in row Update.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //int id = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    TextBox tname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("nam");
   //to get value of first cell
    string str = row.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: from where you get the textbox name as `nam`

Comment: That didn't work at all. got an empty alertbox (so no value was found)

Comment: that is dummy name u can change name as per your controls name. But in your grid there is not any textbox control. So u can get the value of any cell using row.Cells[0].text .

Comment: Still nothing. Just an empty string